# Sharper upper bound for remainder term of $P_2(x)$ of $ e^x\cos(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

> I am asked to give a sharp upper bound on the remainder term $R_2(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ for the Taylor polynomial about $x=0 $ of the function $f(x)=e^x \cos(x)$.

**So far I have worked through the problem but I am unsure of my final steps, I feel that  I can improve on my estimation, but do not know a good method**.

I will first determine the derivatives and the Taylor polynomial about $x=0$, denote it by $P_2 (x)$:

---

We are asked to give the second-order Taylor polynomial about $x=0$ of the function $f(x)= e^x \cos(x)$ we first determine the constant term:
 $$f(0)= e^0 \cos(0)= 1 \cdot 1=1$$
 Using the product rule we find:
 $$ f'(x)= e^x \cos(x) - e^x \sin(x)= e^x(\cos(x)-\sin(x))$$
 Hence:
 $$ f' (0)= e^0 (\cos(0) - \sin(0))= 1 \cdot(1-0) =1$$
 We move to the next step of differentiation:
 $$ f '' (x)= e^x (\cos(x)-\sin(x))+ e^x (-\sin(x)-\cos(x))= -2 \cdot e^x( \sin(x))$$
 $$ f'' (0)= -2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 =0$$
 We find that:
 $$ P_2 (x)=1 + x $$

---

The remainder term for some $\xi \in [0, x]$ and $x 
 \in \mathbb R$ is now given by:
  $$ R_2 (x) = \frac{(x-0)^3}{(3!)} f'''(\xi)$$
  We first determine $f'''(x)$, recall that:
  $$ f'' (x) =  -2e^x \sin(x)$$
  We again employ the product rule and collect the exponential:
  $$ f'''(x)= -2 e^x \sin(x) -2e^x \cos(x) =-2 e^x(\sin(x) + \cos(x))$$
  Such that we find:
  $$ R_2 (x) = - \frac{2}{6} x^3 e^\xi (\sin \xi + \cos \xi )= - \frac{1}{6} x^3 e^\xi (\sin \xi + \cos \xi )$$
  We will now determine an upper bound for $x \in [0,1]$. Recall that from high school we can combine trigonometric functions as:
   $$\cos \xi + \sin  \xi = \sqrt2  \sin(\xi + \frac{\pi}{4}) $$
   We will now use this, so observe:
   $$ |R_2 (x)| = |- \frac{1}{3} x^3 e^\xi (\sin \xi + \cos \xi )|= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}|x|^3 e^{\xi}  |\sin(\xi + \pi / 4)|$$
   Since the exponent is a a strictly positive function and since the absolute value of a product is the product of absolute values. Observe the $\sin$ function is bounded by $1$ and that $\xi \in [0,x]$  hence $ 0 \leq \xi \leq 1$, we use this to write:
   $$\boxed{ |R_2|\leq \frac{\sqrt 2}{3} 1^3 e^1 \cdot 1 = \frac{\sqrt 2 e}{3}  \approx 1.28}$$

**This is my final bound, but of course, the $\sin (x + \pi /4)$ is maximal whenever $x= \pi/4 \neq 1$. I need some better argument to make this bound sharper. At least, I think so. **

Comment: What's wrong with the bound you obtained? Namely that $|R_2(x)|\le\frac{e\sqrt 2}3|x|^3$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: You gave sort of a hint by finding a bounding polynomial, rather than a bounding value.

Comment: It's not clear what your comment means.

Comment: Well, in the end I say that$ |R_2| \leq 1.28$, but your statement is rather that the error term is bounded by some cubic polynomial on the interval  $[0,1]$. I did not think of this as a viable answer to the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we know that in the interval $[0, 1]$, we have the value $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the cosine is maximal here. If we do not get rid of the $x$ we get a polynomial upper bound. In this case we get:
  $$ \boxed{ |R_2|\leq \frac{\sqrt 2}{3} e^{\pi/4} \cdot x^3\approx 1.033922 x^3} $$
this was the desired approach to the question, as it turned out.

The mistake I made earlier in this question was using both $x=\pi/4$ and $x=1$ to get an extremal value for $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ and $e^x$ respectively. Instead, picking one is enough. This gives a sharper upper bound, as desired.